# Center drawn text

Tags: vb.net, center, drawstring

I'm drawing text in VB.net by using:

`gfx.DrawString(_bText, New Font("Tahoma", 5), Brushes.Black, New Point(25, 5))`

where gfx is a graphics object using my control.  The x point is correct but I need the y to be the center of the current contol (vertically).  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextRenderer has a VerticalCenter flag:

```
Dim r As New Rectangle(25, 0, myControl.ClientSize.Width - 25, _
                              myControl.ClientSize.Height)

Using myFont As New Font("Tahoma", 5)
  TextRenderer.DrawText(gfx, _bText, myFont, r, _
                        Color.Black, Color.Empty, _
                        TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter)
End Using
```

Comment: TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter and HorizontalCenter can be combinded using an OR.  In C# it is like this: TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter

Answer (score 3):

You need to look at the [Graphics.MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx) method

Using this you can find the Height of your text in the context you give it. You then need to find the Y value to start drawing your text using something like this:

```
(ControlHeight/2) - (TextHeight/2)
```

Comment: I'm drawing text on an image and this lead me to better results than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use the DrawString overload that takes a StringFormat argument.  Set its Alignment property to Center.